# Wrap text to new line inside table cells

Tags: html, css

I have a terrible CSS bug that makes text content appear outside of the table cell. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/6ge7fd8j/) with the problem.

[image]

I would like the content to appear with a linebreak or similar inside the table cell but nothing is possible no matter what I try. I tried changing the `width` attribute for the table cells but then nothing is possible. What can I do about this bug?

```html
<td class="title-details">
  <a href="/social/group/infosys-scrum-team/event/uppfoljning-av-organisationsforandringen-2/" title="Klicka för att se alla detaljer">



    Uppföljning av organisationsförändringen - Avstämningspunkt på IT-ledningsmötet</a>
  <span class="title-details-short">

                                     <a href="/social/group/infosys-scrum-team/event/uppfoljning-av-organisationsforandringen-2/" title="Uppföljning av organisationsförändringen
    • Den ursprungliga tidplanen hade en uppföljningspunkt
    den 6 maj
    • Den stryks och fokus läggs på förändringsarbetet
    tillsammans med cheferna
    • Planerade uppföljningspunkter
    • 16/9 – Uppstartsaktivitet kopplat till
    organisationsförändringen
    • 25/11 – Avstämningspunkt på IT-ledningsmötet
    • 2/12 – Avstämningspunkt på ITA-mötet 2/12">...</a>

                                </span>
  <span class="title-details-long">Uppföljning av organisationsförändringen
    • Den ursprungliga tidplanen hade en uppföljningspunkt
    den 6 maj
    • Den stryks och fokus läggs på förändringsarbetet
    tillsammans med cheferna
    • Planerade uppföljningspunkter
    • 16/9 – Uppstartsaktivitet kopplat till
    organisationsförändringen
    • 25/11 – Avstämningspunkt på IT-ledningsmötet
    • 2/12 – Avstämningspunkt på ITA-mötet 2/12</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Pare your code example down to a bare minimum and post it in your question.

Comment: It's not a CSS bug, it's your code that's the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the following style:

```
#events .event_search_table td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

remove this and your text will wrap

If you want to keep this style but not wrap that particular column, then override the style:

```
#events .event_search_table td.title-details {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `white-space: normal;`?

```
td.title-details a {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv313gzy/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `white-space: nowrap` property from td i.e  class `.title-details`

```
#events .event_search_table .title-details {
      white-space: normal;
    }
```

or you can give css property to `.title-detail` class

```
#events .event_search_table .title-details {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```